# How to deal with non-fixed xelement?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

im using a method to parse a xdocument to an object but i have a situation in this line of code:

```
 var xElementTax = xElementXml.Element(xn + "tax");
 var aux = xElementTax.Element(xn + "taxNN").Value;
```

In the ***taxNN*** XName the ***NN*** part is a random number, i.e: tax01, tax02, tax03 and goes on. It could be any two digit number.

How can i deal with this situation wheres i dont have a fixed tag? The only fixed part of the tag is the **tax** word.

Thanks.

Comment: And what does the surrounding XML look like?

Comment: `xElementTax` is singular, how many taxNN tags do you expect?

Comment: @HenkHolterman just one

Answer (score 0):

Are you looping through all the elements of xElementTax?

If so you can just go with this:

```
foreach(XElement auxElement in xElementTax.Elements)
{
    var aux = auxElement.Value;
    // And so on
}
```

If you want only those which match "taxNN" you can go instead with:

```
foreach(XElement auxElement in xElementTax.Elements.Where(x => x.Name.ToString().StartsWith(xn + "tax"))
{
    var aux = auxElement.Value;
    ...
}
```

If there's only going to be one of them you can go with:

```
XElement auxElement = xElementTax.Elements.Where(
    x => x.Name.ToString().StartsWith(xn + "tax").FirstOrDefault();
var aux = auxElement.Value;
```

Comment: I think you mean xElementXml.

Comment: Looks like it's been edited since I saw it. Let me fix. Thanks for the heads up!